# Unusual file under Android on SGH-1337M DO_NOT_DELETE

Tags: sms

Under Android Folder I have two files Data and DO_NOT_DELETE, within the DO NOT DELETE file are some sub files opening these in notebook shows text conversations from my text messages. Why would android save these texts to a file that requests do not delete?
Also it only shows up when I plug into my computer. On my phone under files only the Data folder shows up. What is this do not delete file and where did it come from?

Comment: Could you clarify the full path of the folder? Is it in internal or external storage?